# First time installing Android Studio - getting an error

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just installed Android Studio for the first time to learn how to make apps.
But I stumbled across an error that I get whenever I create a project.
The error I get is this one:

> `"Render problem - Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current Theme.`

So I did some searching and found multiple posts like mine and the solution to this problem for everyone was to add the following piece of code.

```
<item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
```

I added the line of code into the application theme, and i am getting another error now.

> Render problem - Couldn't resolve resource @style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout

styles.xml looks like this

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

This line

```
@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout
```

is redmarked and while hovering over it, it says "symbol cannot be resolved"

Also, this is my build.gradle file, here you can see that i'm using the latest design library and i'm compiling against API 28

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fredrikbiten.myapplication2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I haven't written any line of code, this was all default when creating the project. Anyone who knows a solution?

Comment: try creating a new project with inbuilt templates e.g. Navigation Drawer Activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem caused by the API 28. Just move to API 27 (compile and target version, dependencies, etc) and wait they fix this.

I haven't found a real solution to this, rebuild, clean, invalidate caches, etc. A tried all StackOverflow answer and they didn't work too.

Answer (score 1):

So i got it to work. I changed API Level and the design version to 27 from 28. works now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added the line that you describe:

```
<item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
```

to the **AppTheme**, not to the **AppTheme.NoActionBar** and problem solved!
Hope this leads you in the right direction.

Comment: My bad. I added the line of code to apptheme, but, it gives me the same error. "Render problem - Couldn't resolve resource @style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout

Comment: In my styles.xml file this line is red and it says that it cannot resolve symbol @style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout

Comment: Hum..., try **"Build/Clean Project"** and/or **"File/Invalidate Caches / Restart..."** and then rebuild your project

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have the Android Support Design library included in your project. It should look something like this: `com.android.support:design:24.0.0` in the `dependencies` area of your app-level `build.gradle` file.

You should use the support library version that goes along with the `compileSdkVersion` that you've specified. So for example, if you're compiling against API level 27, you should use `com.android.support:design:27.1.1`

Comment: Hello. I went into the build.gradle file and checked the version. It does look alright to me, i'm compiling against API 28.   "implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'"

Comment: Try restarting Android Studio.

Comment: Hi, i have tried that multiple times. I have even reinstalled Android studio 2 times

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by unchecking the 'backward compability(AppCompact)'

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GECK.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCx5R.png]

And I didn't have any issue after this! May be this is bug which will be fixed in later versions.